# Database Design: Store data from Physical Form

Tags: database, database-design, document

First of all, i have read some other solutions relating to this question such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662525/database-design-for-storing-checklists-and-results)

However, i have a slightly different problem.

Basically i need to build a registration form such that a user can register and submit his/her registration details.

For each registration, it has a document-checklist kind of thing where user would appropriately fill the form.

The document checklist allows user to tick the appropriate box if he/she has the corresponding document. There is also a mandatory field for each checklist.

Example of the checklist is as follows (example only):

1. Driving License Card []Yes []No If yes, specify the ID: ............

So far i have the following tables

- tb_registration (reg_id, reg_no, reg_date, ...)
- tb_user (usr_id, usr_unique, usr_city, ...)
- tb_attachment (reg_id, doc_id)
- tb_documents (doc_id, doc_filename, doc_size, ...)
- tb_reg_checklist(reg_id, chk_id)
- tb_chk_details(chk_id, [This is the part that i am confused with])

Basically with the above structure, every user can register one or more. For each registration user must fill in the appropriate document checklist.

Every registration could also have one or more document attached to them, hence the tb_attachment. In this case every registration could have one or more attachment where the attachment details (the actual documents) is stored in the tb_documents.

I am currently stuck on how to elaborate on the document checklist part.

Should i go with one big table with the tb_chk_details so that it has a structure like this

chk_id
chk_license [ENUM]
chk_license_no
chk_doc_one [ENUM]
chk_doc_one_no
chk_doc_two [ENUM]
chk_doc_two_no

and so on....

Or is there a better way to mitigate this kind of problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

What about storing the list of checkboxes separately and then store the responses?

- tb_chk_details(chk_id, chk_text, chk_order)
- tb_user_chk_responses(usr_id, chk_id)

That way you can draw the list of checkboxes on the page solely using tb_chk_details, and then when a user saves their responses, you write records to tb_user_chk_responses.

Makes it easier to change the checkboxes over time.